# What does it mean for a method to be a classmethod and what does parameter * represent?

Tags: python

Looking into the Python documentation, I came across the following page:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes

Here, the third argument of `int.from_bytes()` is `*`. What does `*` represent and why can it be ignored in the examples?

Also, the `fromkeys(seq[, value])` method is said to be a classmethod, but what exactly does this mean? What class does this method belong to?

Comment: You probably don't want to ask for many different things in the same question

Comment: Second question: Not too surprisingly, it's explained in the documentation of [**parameters**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter). In this case it means that the _signed_ argument can be supplied only by the keyword (unlike the first two).